# How to insert a custom field in to the advanced PDF template of NetSuite?

Tags: pdf, netsuite, freemarker, suitescript2.0

I want to display the **Serial Number** field in the PDF printout for Purchase Order. The internal ID for the field is **custcol_xml_serial_num**.

The **Serial Number** field can be found in the template for Invoice, but somehow it can not be found in the template for PO.

The snapshots of templates are as follows:

---

*The template for PO:*
[image: PO template]

*The template for Invoice: (the Serial Number can be found in the filter)*
[image: Invoice template]

I have no idea how to make the **Serial Number** displayed in the template. Is there any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HTML editor and adding ${record.custcol_xml_serial_num}.

Also make sure that the body field itself is set to be applied to Purchases.